# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'

Tags: python, casting, while-loop, int

```
   ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'
```

I'm fairly new to Python (Python3 by the way!) and I'm stumped on this problem. I get why the error is showing (which is because I'm trying to get a string when I'm using integers) but I'm clueless as to how to get around it. I want for my program to read integers in, according to the conditions, and exit when it reads the string 'q'. It might be an easy fix, but I really need another set of eyes on my code. I've been wrestling with this for longer than I'm proud of.

```
def main():
    aliveRow = []
    aliveCol = []
    rowAlive =''
    colAlive = -1
    row = 5
    column = 5
    while rowAlive != 'q':
        rowAlive = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on (or 'q' to exit:) ")
        if rowAlive != 'q' and int(rowAlive) < 0 or int(rowAlive) > row - 1:
            print('that is no a valid value; please enter a number \n \t between 0 and ', row - 1, 'inclusive....')
        elif rowAlive != 'q' and int(rowAlive) >= 0 and int(rowAlive) <= row - 1:
            aliveRow.append(rowAlive)
        else:
            print()
```

Comment: always show error message

Comment: Apart from the missing close bracket, I can not reproduce your error.

Comment: Your error happens when you input `'q'`. Try inputting `q` instead, without quotes. Also, you are missing a close parentheses in ` int(rowAlive >= 0`

Comment: fixed the bracket part... my bad. Also @DavidRobinson are you suggesting I define q as some integer and do it that way?

Comment: @Joseph - No. When you run your code and it prompts you for input, type in just `q` and hit return. Do not surround it in quotes.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare When I do that my code doesn't run and I get the NameError: global name 'q' is not defined

Comment: Which integer is both less than zero and greater than minus one?  I think your `if` condition can never be true, can it?

Comment: In Python 2 use `raw_input()` in place of `input()`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah, I found another error...I'm sorry everyone, it was supposed to be row - 1 !

Comment: I assure you I'm using python3 ! raw_input does not work!

Comment: also changed the boolean and to or... to actually get the error..I apologize I'm very tired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what happens when you enter `q`.

- The first part of the `if` condition is not met - `rowAlive != 'q'` returns `False`.
- This means that the next part of the expression (`int(rowAlive) < 0`), connected by `and`, doesn't need to be evaluated; the `and` operator aborts after the first falsy value.
- However, `and` has a higher precendence than `or`. `if a and b or c` is the same as `if (a and b) or c`. 
  Therefore, the last part of your expression needs to be tested: `int(rowAlive) > row - 1`, and Python can't calculate `int('q')`.

Use

```
if rowAlive != 'q' and (int(rowAlive) < 0 or int(rowAlive) > row - 1):
```

to solve the problem. It would have been even better not to repeat yourself:

```
while True:
    rowAlive = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on (or 'q' to exit:) ")
    if rowAlive == 'q':
        break
    elif int(rowAlive) < 0 or int(rowAlive) > row - 1:
        print('that is not a valid value; please enter a number \n \t between 0 and ', row-1, 'inclusive....')
    else:
        aliveRow.append(rowAlive)
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT! Also...sorry to ask, but how would I do this same thing without the break?

Comment: You need the `break` to get out of the `while` loop. The alternative would be (as you did) to test whether `rowAlive != 'q'` at all points, which is repetitive and prone to errors (as you saw).